# Xamarin Forms Item Templates Missing in Visual Studio

Tags: xamarin.forms

I had to restore my Windows to a previous restore point and then Xamarin stopped working.  I ended up uninstalling Xamarin and Visual Studio 2015 to get Xamarin working again, which it mostly is.  I cannot update Xamarin Forms to the latest stable 2.3.3.180 but 2.3.3.175 is working for now.

The most troublesome issue is when I right click my PCL project and select Add->New Item, in the list of Installed templates there is no Cross-Platform folder and nowhere to select "Forms Xaml Page" item.  How can I get these templates installed? Have done reinstall and repair on both VS and Xamarin and I can't get these templates to show up.

Thanks,

Tony

Answer (score 1):

See my post here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42341624/2274377

1. C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\
2. Find the correct subfolder. This can be tricky. I had a Xamarin folder, but that was not the right one. In my case it was folder
   wa13kl1p.m3s. However, open your folders and check it there is some
   Xamarin.Forms.Templates... files in it.
3. Inside that folder navigate to the T/P/CSharp folder.
4. Copy the Cross-Platform folder over to C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio
   2015\Templates\ProjectTemplates\Visual C#

   **Same thing for the ItemTemplates:**

But this time navigate to T/I/CSharp folder.

Copy the Cross-Platform folder over to C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio2015\Templates\ItemTemplates\Visual C#

Comment: but my `Cross-Platform` folder has no files. Can i download it from some where from the internet ?

Comment: Don't think so. Try updating and / or reinstalling Visual Studio 2017

Comment: I have [perform a thorough uninstall for Xamarin for Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/troubleshooting/questions/uninstall-xamarin-vs) and reinstalled only xamarin by running setup, which is quite faster this time, it took less than 2 hours and then just updated xamarin from tools/options/xamarin and updated all the packages to latest version after creating new cross plateform app and it just works