# no .WinPhone template in Visual Studio 2015 Community Xamarin Cross-Platform

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

I try to create cross-platform app in Xamarin Visual Studio, and its what i got (less template):

It actually like this problem [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41767780/visual-studio-2015-community-xamarin-cross-platform-templates-missing?answertab=active&newreg=be639647964d42a2b8591e6801ad98af), it because an update of new xamarin app.

I choose cross platform app, Blank App and use Native UI

There's no error or warning, but i missing the .WinPhone solution in [Solution Exploler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KbhL.jpg)

Note :

1. Actually my first question
2. Using Visual Studio Community 2015, update 3
3. With Xamarin stable version 4.3.0.784

Answer (score 1):

Wimdows phone is not avaliable with new xamarin update but you can add windows phone project and install xamarin.forms library